# Pearson’s correlation test

Tags: r

I have a situation like this:

```
Gene       SAMPLE1   SAMPLE2 
 G1         0.33      0.21  
 G2         0.45      0.324 
 G3         0.765     0.654 
 G4         0.98      0.543 
 G5         0.565     0.13
 G6         0.123     0.943
 G7         0.321     0.572
....       ...       ......
```

data are not real data.
i need to: compute the p-values of a two sided Pearson’s correlation test.

Can anyone help me please? I'm quite new in R.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cor.test` to peform this correlation test. This is part of any standard R distribution. In your case `with(dat, cor.test(Sample1, Sample2))` will perform the test you need.

Googling for `R correlation test` returned the documentation of `cor.test` as the first result.

Answer (score 0):

As said above you can use the cor.test() function:

```
 cor.test(data$SAMPLE1, data$SAMPLE2)
```

If you are a beginner in R, correlation test between two variables is extensively described here :

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-test-between-two-variables

You can also do pearson correlation test online without any installation here :

http://www.sthda.com/english/rsthda/correlation.php